# checkbox и radio во всех браузерах будет работать верно?

Tags: html, css, css3

Доброго всем времени! Подскажите, пожалуйста, я все правильно сделал? Во всех браузерах это будет работать верно? А также на телефонах и планшетах будет работать правильно? Благодарю!

```css
.wrp .checkbox {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}

.wrp .checkbox+label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrp .checkbox:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrp .checkbox:not(checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
}

.wrp .checkbox:not(checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 26px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.wrp .checkbox:not(checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 2px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: all .2s;
}

.wrp .checkbox:checked+label:before {
  background: #9FD468;
}

.wrp .checkbox:checked+label:after {
  left: 26px;
}

.wrp .checkbox:focus+label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}

.wrp .radio {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 17px;
  height: 17px;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
}

.wrp .radio+label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrp .radio:not(checked) {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.wrp .radio:not(checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
}

.wrp .radio:not(checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
}

.wrp .radio:not(checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.wrp .radio:checked+label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.wrp .radio:focus+label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}

.wrp input[type='reset'] {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrp input[type='reset']:active {
  background: #BDC0CC;
}

.wrp input[type='reset']:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">

  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
  <label for="checkbox-1">Мой выбор</label>

  <br><br>

  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-2">
  <label for="checkbox-2">Мой выбор</label>

  <br><br><br><br>

  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-1">Мой выбор</label>

  <br><br>

  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-2">Мой выбор</label>

</div>
```

Comment: `.radio:not(checked)` - не имеет смысла, если конечно "checked" - это не тег (что вряд ли), то будет отрабатывать всегда. По логике должно быть `.radio:not(:checked)`, а в остальном вроде ничего противозаконного.

Comment: в `:not` тут вообще нет особо смысла в принципе. Это просто отрабатывает явно не так как вы ожидаете, оно просто срабатывает и все, по этому это условие можно опустить вообще.

Comment: @LADYX Исходя из опыта, могу сказать, что все будет отлично. И да, :not вообще не нужен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментария верно указали - `:not()` лишний. А также ошибка в написании псевдокласса `:checked` (пропущен знак `:`). Убрав лишнее и объединив пару правил, немного сократил код CSS:

```css
/* checkbox */
.wrp .checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  height: 17px; width: 17px;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0;
}
.wrp .checkbox+label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrp .checkbox+label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px; left: 0;
  height: 26px; width: 50px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  background: #CDD1DA;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  }
  .wrp .checkbox:checked+label::before {
    background: #9FD468;
  }
  .wrp .checkbox:focus+label::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}
.wrp .checkbox+label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px; left: 2px;
  height: 22px; width: 22px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: all .2s;
  }
  .wrp .checkbox:checked+label::after {
    left: 26px;
}

/* radio */
.wrp .radio {
  position: absolute;
  height: 17px; width: 17px;
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0;
}
.wrp .radio+label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrp .radio+label::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px; left: 0;
  height: 22px; width: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
  }
  .wrp .radio:focus+label::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255, 255, 0, .5);
}
.wrp .radio+label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px; left: 4px;
  height: 16px; width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .2s;
  }
  .wrp .radio:checked+label::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrp">
  <br><br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
  <label for="checkbox-1">Мой выбор</label>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-1" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-1">Мой выбор</label>
  <br><br>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio-2" name="radio">
  <label for="radio-2">Мой выбор</label>
</div>
```

А так, да, симпатичные контролы ;-) Должны работать везде.